# How to cancel Ag-grid OnFilterChanged event?

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

`onFilterChanged()/OnFilterModified()` events give a call back when filter model is changed. how to cancel this event and prevent reloading of data?

Comment: if my answer solved your problem, please mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try `event.stopPropagation()`, you can bind grid event with your method then you can use  `event.stopPropagation()` in your method

```html
<ag-grid-angular (onFilterChanged)="filterChanged($event)"></ag-grid-angular>
```

```js
filterChanged(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: i tried both event.stopPropagation and event.preventDefault . neither of them worked.